# Use ajax to get Json from server

Tags: jquery, json, zend-framework

I'm a big beginner in jQuery. I'm trying to get some Json from the server: there is my code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/addemail",
        type:'POST',
        data: $("form#form12").serialize(),  
        success: function(my_json) { 
                 // I suppose that Json returned by the addmail() is in the var: my_json ?
                //inject my_json inside some <td >      

               } 
        });
```

My php function (I'm using Zend):

```
 public function addemailAction(){
$data=array(array('Email'=>'abc@gmail.com',
                     'Name'=>'Abc Def')
                            );
$this->_helper->json->sendJson($data);


    }
```

Comment: Don't you have to use some controller in that url as well? And can you be more specific on what's going wrong in your code at present?

Comment: don't forget to add `dataType: 'json'` then try something like `alert(my_json.Email);` inside `success`

Comment: @raina77ow: just trying to get json returned by the addemail();

Comment: @Spokey: i added dataType and i get in the alert(mu_json.Email): it s working, Thank you so much.

Comment: My guess is you aren't actually returning any json since you're getting an empty alert. You're probably also using  jquery 1.8 or older, in 1.9 an empty json response would have thrown an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the dataType to the ajax call

`dataType:'json'`

And in your `success` function you get your data by referencing the array names from the `my_json` object

```
function(my_json) { 
     alert(my_json.Email);
     alert(my_json.Name);
}
```

not knowledgeable of what

`$this->_helper->json->sendJson($data);`

does, im sure it just puts out the json code, but you can output the json with `json_encode` as well a bit shorter then using the object chain.

`echo json_encode($data);`

Answer (score 0):

This is just added to help you along with developing in Zend, since you already got your question answered.

If you are using Zend Framework 1 a great way to see if your server is actually responding with json is directly accessing it through url:

```
http://site/applicationName/public/controllerName/ActionNameThatReturnsJsonData/format/json
```

When you access it you should see the reply array coded in Json format. Remember that Zend always asks for a "/format/json" to be present in the url in order to know that the request is json. I figure you are using either "contextSwithc or Ajaxcontext" in order to disable both layout and view rendering. If that is so, then all you need to do in the controller is any of these:

If you use ContextSwitch:

```
$this->view->whateeverVariableNameYouwant = $data;
```

The ContextSwitch _helper will automatically parse your data to json. Whatever "variable" you pass to your view, it will get echoed as json data. The same as doing:

```
echo Zend_Json::encode($data);
```